# Debezium property snapshot.new.tables not working

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

The debezium connector works fine when initiated. But when i add new tables to the table list, instead of taking a snapshot of new tables, it starts reading from bin log even though i have provided snaphot.new.tables = parallel.
Here is my config.

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "database.dbname": "db_name",
  "database.hostname": "host",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "user",
  "database.password": "pass",
  "database.server.name": "server",
  "database.include.list": "db_name",
  "table.include.list": "table1,table2",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
  "name": "server",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "stopic",
  "offset.flush.interval.ms": "5000",
  "offset.flush.timeout.ms": "60000",
  "slot.name": "slot_name",
  "snapshot.lock.timeout.ms": "99999999",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
  "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
  "snapshot.new.tables":"parallel",
  "sanitize.field.names": "true",
  "snapshot.fetch.size": 50000,
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
  "database.initial.statements": "SET SESSION wait_timeout=28800;SET SESSION interactive_timeout=28800;"
}
```

Comment: What Debezium version are you using?

Comment: same problem "snapshot.new.tables": "parallel", is not working with 

debezium-connector-mysql-1.8.1.Final-plugin